# UWP app after deploy not work (An error occurred while sending the request)

Tags: azure, uwp

1. There are development PC with VS 2015.
2. In solution on UWP_App + WebApp.
3. UWP success connect to localhost WebApp.
4. Create VM  with Win10 in Azure.
5. Deploy (copy) and start WebApp - work good from edge an chrome
6. Create UWP package and deploy in VM
7. **On HttpClient.PostAsync "An error occurred while sending the request"**
8. Create VM with Win10 (with VS2015 from gallery) in Azure
9. Deploy (copy) and start WebApp
10. Create UWP package and deploy in VM
11. **On HttpClient.PostAsync "An error occurred while sending the request"**
12. Run UWP from VS - **NO ERROR**
13. **Next run NO ERROR TOO**

What is that? 
How detect connection error?

Comment: Did you check the capabilities of the UWP app in the manifest. Is `Internet (Client)` enabled?

Comment: Yes.     <Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <Capability Name="privateNetworkClientServer" />
    <Capability Name="internetClientServer" />

Comment: Are you running in same Configurations "Debug" and "Release"? When you run from VS is it running in the same config like the deployed version?

Comment: Same config run and deploy. I have two VM with same UWP_APP version. 1 working (one start from VS) 2 not working. 1VM deploy with ps1, 2VM run from VS, uninstall, deploy with ps1

Comment: Please check the network linked,by ping command in each VM firstly.

Comment: Network - ok. Deploy with VS - ok. Deploy with ps1 (powershell) - cant connect.

Comment: @AlexandrSulimov do you found a solution? Have the same issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default app not allow loopback. Checkbox in project properties in Debug tab - not work.

**checknetisolation loopbackexempt -a -n=< packagename >**

Comment: What does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

had the same issue, it was just internet connectivity.